# How do I change my default shell on a AWS instance?

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2

I want to change my shell from the default bash shell to zsh on my Amazon EC2 instances. How do I go about doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try using the `chsh` command.

e.g.

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

You can confirm the location of zsh by running `whereis zsh`, or alternatively simply run

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

If you want to change the shell for a user account other than the one you're logged into, you'll need to run it as root, so to change john's shell, do:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) john
```

Note that you'll need to log out and log back in for the change to go into effect. If you're using Gnome or some other window manager, you'll need to completely log out of that session as well—simply closing and opening your terminal is insufficient.

Comment: I did try that, but with the root user!! My AMI Image has ubuntu rather than root. Had to switch to ubuntu user to change the shell! Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @Paddy if you are root you can change it for another user by running `chsh -s /bin/zsh username`.

Comment: Awesome :) Much easier. Thanks for that info too.

Comment: I'm getting: `chsh: /usr/local/bin/zsh is an invalid shell`

Comment: @We are the World: You need to add /usr/local/bin/zsh as a new line to /etc/shells

Comment: I use a lightly different version `sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)`

Comment: getting a `chsh: /usr/local/bin/zsh: non-standard shell` message

Comment: Since `chsh -s /bin/zsh` emits a password prompt, and the default AWS image gives you a ec2-user with a ssh key (don't know password) I had to do `sudo passwd root`, then give a new password, then `sudo passwd ec2-user`, then I could to `chsh -s /bin/zsh` with the ec2-user's password (you do not need to sudo chsh)

Answer (score 29):

Open /etc/passwd:

```
sudo vi /etc/passwd
```

Find the line with your username:

```
username:x:1634231:100:Your Name:/home/username:/bin/bash
```

and replace bash with zsh:

```
username:x:1634231:100:Your Name:/home/username:/bin/zsh
```

Log out and log in back for the changes to take effect.

Comment: It's better to use `chsh`, but if you're *really* going to edit `/etc/passwd` by hand, at least use the `vipw` command.

Comment: I don't have chsh on my machine. Also, for some weird reason my /etc/passwd file is regularly being overwritten by the default one. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: **Don't touch /etc/passwd.** There are better ways to do this that do not require messing with the passwd tool!

Comment: On Ubuntu AMIs it is not possible to use `chsh` for ubuntu user since it requires a password. Editing `/etc/passwd` file does the trick. More info [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83460).

Answer (score 19):

I came here to just add more additional information.
If you have troubles when install **zsh** in **Amazon Linux AMI** by Amazon, like when you run:

```
sudo chsh $(which zsh) : // chsh command not found
```

Then you should install **util-linux-user**:

```
sudo yum install util-linux-user
```

(by default Amazon Linux AMI only has **lchsh**, but I can not figure how it work).

Then run the following command, it should work:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for AWS AMI :)

Comment: With `lchsh`, just do `sudo lchsh -i ec2-user`.

Comment: You can skip interactive.  `which git-shell | lchsh git` for example.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, inside GNOME terminal, making changes via chsh won't have the expected effect...

To get over this problem, do this:

- Right click in terminal
- Profiles -> Profile Preferences
- Under "Title and Command" tab, tick "Run a custom command instead of my shell" and provide the path to zsh executable.
- Restart Terminal.

Peace.

P.S. Don't have 10 reputation to post images, so all texty instructions. :)

Comment: You have the rep you need now. :P

Answer (score 0):

one line

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

**Extra Info:**
after that you'll **probably want to do this ones**

```
git clone https://github.com/zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting.git \
  ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/fast-syntax-highlighting

git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions

nano ~/.zshrc
```

find plugins=(git)
Append zsh-autosuggestions & zsh-syntax-highlighting to plugins() like this

plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions fast-syntax-highlighting)

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance. But, when i tried doing:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ chsh -s /bin/zsh         
Password: 
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

I got a password prompt, which failed with auth error because quite frankly I'm not sure of what to put there for sudo user.

So, I tried adding sudo and command didn't give any error. But, when i ssh'ed later, I still got BASH as default SHELL.

What worked for me was the below command:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

This changed the default shell for current user and it stayed that way for each time I ssh'ed into the machine.

Success! :)