# change default shell from zsh to bash

Tags: bash, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux, zsh

I'm trying to change my default shell in RHEL5 from zsh to bash. 
I tried to the methods mentioned in this [thead](https://superuser.com/questions/231735/how-do-i-change-my-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh). By typing `sudo /usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash`,  the system says `sudo: /usr/bin/chsh: command not found`. But the /usr/bin/chsh is there. Another way I found is to edit /etc/passwd file with my usrid, but it forbids me from editing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you running it as root? You should be able to change your own shell with just `chsh`.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure `/usr/bin/chsh` has execute permissions by running `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/chsh`.

---

You should be able to run `chsh` using your own account. Otherwise you'd be setting `root`'s shell. Try the following:

```
chsh -s $( which bash )
```

Comment: yes, the problem was due to execute permission of chsh. Now, I got a new error when I execute "chsh -s bash", it says "setpwnam: Permission denied. Shell *NOT* changed.  Try again later."

Comment: @user268451 You can specify for which account to set the shell, e.g. like the following: `sudo chsh -s $( which bash) danielbeck` (`danielbeck` of course is the user name)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your default shell is already `bash`.

**To know your default shell on Red Hat:**

```
finger youruser
```

output:

```
Login: XXXXXXXX                         Name: XXXXXX XXXXXX
Directory: /Home/XXXXXX                 Shell: /bin/zsh
Office: XXXXXX
Office Phone: XXXXXXXXXX                Home Phone: XXXXXXXXXX
...
```

**If the `Shell` information is not `/bin/bash` then use `ypchfn`:**

```
$ ypchsh
Changing NIS account information for XXXX on XXXXXXXXX.
Please enter password:

Changing login shell for XXXX on XXXXXXXXX.
To accept the default, simply press return. To use the
system's default shell, type the word "none".
Login shell [/bin/zsh]: /bin/bash

The login shell has been changed on XXXXXXXXX.
```

**Check again your default shell:**

```
finger youruser
```

output:

```
Login: XXXXXXXX                         Name: XXXXXX XXXXXX
Directory: /Home/XXXXXX                 Shell: /bin/bash
Office: XXXXXX
Office Phone: XXXXXXXXXX                Home Phone: XXXXXXXXXX
...
```

Let me know if it is OK for you...
Cheers